# Transposing Data From Web in to Rows with Loop

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, transpose

I am trying to scrape a large volume of data using my rather basic excel skills. I am using this as a guide (http://www.familycomputerclub.com/scrpae-pull-data-from-websites-into-excel.html), and have got it to work for my data, but now trying to amend the code to meet my requirements.

I have about 10,000 Roll numbers listed in columns, and need to scrape the data from this site (last 10 digits being the roll numbers): http://www.winnipegassessment.com/AsmtPub/english/propertydetails/details.aspx?pgLang=EN&isRealtySearch=true&RollNumber=2011016000

Basically, rather than adding new worksheets for each page download (as per the guide I have been using above), I would like to keep all the new data on the master page, simply transposing the it in to the row with its corresponding roll number (perhaps from the C column).

My code is as follows:

```
Sub adds()
For x = 1 To 5
Worksheets("RollNo").Select
Worksheets("RollNo").Activate
mystr = "URL;http://www.winnipegassessment.com/AsmtPub/english/propertydetails/details.aspx?pgLang=EN&isRealtySearch=true&RollNumber=2000416000.html"
mystr = Cells(x, 1)
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
'CommandType = 0
.Name = "2000416000_1"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebTables = "2,6,7"  '---> Note: many tables have been selected for import from the website
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ProcessAll()
    Dim c As Range, shtData As Worksheet

    Set shtData = Worksheets("WebQuery")

    For Each c In Worksheets("RollNo").Range("A1:A5").Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            FetchData c.Value
            'move fetched data to the sheet
            With c.EntireRow
                .Cells(2).Value = shtData.Range("A2").Value
                'etc....
            End With
        End If
    Next c

End Sub

Sub FetchData(rollNo)
Const BASE_URL As String = "URL;http://www.winnipegassessment.com/AsmtPub/english/" & _
           "propertydetails/details.aspx?pgLang=EN&isRealtySearch=true&RollNumber="
Dim qt As QueryTable

    With Worksheets("WebQuery")
        On Error Resume Next
        .QueryTables(1).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Cells.Clear
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:=BASE_URL & rollNo, Destination:=.Range("A2"))
            .Name = "2000416000_1"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = "2,6,7"
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I get the following error when I run that: "Run time error 9: Subscript out of range", on line: Set shtData = Worksheets("WebQuery")

Comment: Do you have a worksheet named "WebQuery"?  If not, then add you'll need to add one (or change the name in the code to an existing worksheet you want to use instead)

Comment: Ha - Worked it out just as you wrote that. When I run the script, it just deletes the contents of the B column... Perhaps I have my master file set up incorrectly (I tried to add a pic but the site wouldn't let me).... my A column is made up of the web addresses, for example: url;http://www.winnipegassessment.com/AsmtPub/english/propertydetails/details.aspx?pgLang=EN&isRealtySearch=true&RollNumber=2001118000 and the B column is the corresponding RollNo (in this example: 2001118000)... should I have it set up differently for this to work?

Comment: You'll need to adjust the code for your exact layout.  In my sample code I copied the first cell from the query sheet into column B.  If you want to start at a different place then change `.Cells(2)` to some other column (and of course you'll need to add in the other values from the query sheet...)